# snowsql to gather details about DB its all schemas, tables, view, stages, pipes and so on

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake/snowsql and I have a task something like generating the CSV file with available DB's and all lower INDIVIDUAL objects and again their INDIVIDUAL objects in detail.

can anyone suggest how to gather these details?

Comment: Lots of different ways e.g. using get_ddl or reading through the relevant views in the account_usage schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare
   res resultset;
begin
   --- Create temporary table for resultset
   create or replace temporary table snow_query_temporary
   (sequence number, object_type varchar, database_name varchar, schema_name varchar, name varchar);
   --- Databases
   show databases in account;
   insert into snow_query_temporary (sequence, object_type, database_name)
   select 1, 'Database', "name" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
   --- Schemas
   show schemas in account;
   insert into snow_query_temporary (sequence, object_type, database_name, schema_name)
   select 2, 'Schema', "database_name", "name" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
   --- Tables
   show tables in account;
   insert into snow_query_temporary (sequence, object_type, database_name, schema_name, name)
   select 3, 'Table', "database_name", "schema_name", "name" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
   --- Views
   show views in account;
   insert into snow_query_temporary (sequence, object_type, database_name, schema_name, name)
   select 4, 'View', "database_name", "schema_name", "name" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
   --- Stages
   show stages in account;
   insert into snow_query_temporary (sequence, object_type, database_name, schema_name, name)
   select 5, 'Stage', "database_name", "schema_name", "name" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
   --- File Formats
   show file formats in account;
   insert into snow_query_temporary (sequence, object_type, database_name, schema_name, name)
   select 6, 'File Format', "database_name", "schema_name", "name" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
   --- Sequences
   show sequences in account;
   insert into snow_query_temporary (sequence, object_type, database_name, schema_name, name)
   select 7, 'Sequence', "database_name", "schema_name", "name" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
   --- Pipes
   show pipes in account;
   insert into snow_query_temporary (sequence, object_type, database_name, schema_name, name)
   select 8, 'Pipe', "database_name", "schema_name", "name" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
   --- Streams
   show streams in account;
   insert into snow_query_temporary (sequence, object_type, database_name, schema_name, name)
   select 9, 'Stream', "database_name", "schema_name", "name" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
   --- Tasks
   show tasks in account;
   insert into snow_query_temporary (sequence, object_type, database_name, schema_name, name)
   select 10, 'Task', "database_name", "schema_name", "name" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
   --- Functions
   show functions in account;
   insert into snow_query_temporary (sequence, object_type, database_name, schema_name, name)
   select 11, 'Function', "catalog_name", "schema_name", "name" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) where "is_builtin" = 'N';
   --- Procedures
   show procedures in account;
   insert into snow_query_temporary (sequence, object_type, database_name, schema_name, name)
   select 12, 'Procedure', "catalog_name", "schema_name", "name" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) where "is_builtin" = 'N';
   --- Return results
   res := (select object_type, database_name, schema_name, name from snow_query_temporary order by sequence, database_name, schema_name, name);
   return table (res);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave Appreciate the prompt reply, and the query/script working perfectly, I will further finetune as per the customized requirement and use it, I already tested it on SnF trial account. have one more question on the daily inserted record details/count on database how we can gather those details?

Comment: for the above requirement, I found the useful link by snowflake, which helped me with my requirement. 
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/database_storage_usage_history.html